# Solving a complex integration over the contour $|z| = 1$

Tags: complex-integration, cauchy-integral-formula

> I am trying to solve the following Integral,
>   $$I = \oint_{|z| = 1}\frac{1}{e^{e^{\frac{1}{z}}}}dz$$

My approach has been as follows:
I took "$\ln$" on both sides:
$$\ln(I) = \oint_{|z| = 1}\ln\left(\frac{1}{e^{e^{\frac{1}{z}}}}\right)dz\implies - \oint_{|z|=1}e^{\frac{1}{z}} dz.$$
Then I substitute $\frac{1}{z} = t$, and use Cauchy's Integral formula.
Final answer that I get is: $I = e^{2\pi i}$.

Am I correct in doing this. If not,then Why and what should be my approach?

Thanks a ton.

ANupam

Comment: You cannot swap the order of $\ln$ and integrating.

Comment: Can you please eloborate.

Comment: The $\ln$ of an integral is not the integral of the $\ln$ of the integrand.

Comment: According to PARI/GP, the result is $I=-\frac{2\pi i}{e}$ , but I have no proof.

Comment: Compute the residue of $f(z)$ at $z=0$ by series expansion (it equals $-1/e$).

Answer (score 1):

No, you are not correct: $\ln(\int f)\not=\int \ln(f))$.

Here it is a simpler approach. After letting $w=1/z$, by the Residue Theorem,
$$\begin{align}
\oint_{|z| =1} \frac{1}{\exp(e^{1/z})}\,dz
&=\oint_{|w |=1} \frac{1}{\exp(e^{w})}\cdot \frac{dw}{w^2}\\
&=
2\pi i\,\operatorname{Res}\left(\frac{1}{w^2 \exp(e^{w})},0\right)\\
&=2\pi i \frac{d}{dw}\left(\exp(-e^{w})\right)_{w=0}\\
&= -\frac{2\pi i}{e}.
\end{align}$$